# Existence of a local mininum

Tags: analysis

Let $F: R^{2} \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{|v| \to \infty}f(v) = +\infty$. Then F has a local minimum.
Hint: Think of the Weierstrass Theorem.

I'm trying to solve it, but am having difficulty. Could someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

For an arbitrary $R>0$, let $D_R = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2\}$.

Suppose that $f$ does not obtain a local minimum.  Then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f$ must attain its minimum on the boundary of $D_n$ (why is this the case?  Think Weierstrass).  For each $n$, let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a point in $D_n$ where $f$ attains its minimum.  By our previous argument, $x_n^2 + y_n^2 = n^2$.

Since $D_n \subset D_{n+1}, f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \leq f(x_n,y_n)$ (see if you can make sense of this argument).  So, $\{f(x_n,y_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a non-increasing sequence with $|(x_n,y_n)| \to \infty$.  Why is this a contradiction?